# How can I login to PHPMyAdmin on AWS Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I just set up an AWS Lightsail account and chose the LAMP installation, provided by Bitnami.

According to the [Bitnami documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/phpmyadmin/), to connect to PHPMyAdmin, you create an SSH tunnel and browse to the path giving. Great, I can see the login page, but where do I get the credentials?

*To log in, use username root for MySQL and the application password from the detail page for your cloud server.*

What password are they talking about?

It is not the password to login to my AWS Console. Nor is it, as some threads on the Bitnami site suggest, `bitnami` or `bitnami1`.

Anyone what what password the service is looking for?

Answer (score 26):

The password is found by connecting to server via SSH and running this command in your home directory:

```
cat bitnami_application_password
```

Or this command in any directory:

```
cat $HOME/bitnami_application_password
```

Answer (score 4):

- Username: **root** (it's default)
- Password: **MnQERJ8gcHkQ** (Like this) .Connect to Bitnami Lightsail
  through SSH on Lightsail Dashboard to access the command line tool.
  Using `cat bitnami_application_password`  to get the password, this
  is the same with the password you access to Wordpress (based on
  Lightsail) in the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained in the Bitnami Documentation:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/#using-amazon-lightsail

You can find information there regarding how to find your credentials depending on the AWS service you used to launch your server.